# assignment from incompatible pointer type: forcing the type?

Tags: c, pointers, assignment-operator

```
struct my_struct {
   int p;
   uint32_t *a;
   ...
};
struct my_struct *aa;
```

...

```
struct b {
   uint8_t b;
   ...
};
struct b *bb;
```

At this point `bb` and `aa` have been initialized, `bb` contains valid values.

```
aa->a = &bb->b;
```

However this causes the compiler warning, which makes sense:

`warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]`

Is it safe to do the following?

```
aa->a = (uint32_t *)&bb->b;
```

Comment: Why are you trying to assign a `uint8_t*` to a `uint32_t*`?

Comment: In general? No, hence the type error. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I'm writing an application that opens a `netlink` socket and works with a Linux kernel subsystem. Now, the data may come either as part of the header following the netlink header (and that header is UAPI, where object is `u8`), or the data may come as 32-bit long TLV attribute, hence I have `a` of type `uint32_t` in my_struct.

Comment: Why not use a `union` or `void*` then?  Also, maybe I'm misunderstanding, but it doesn't really explain why you're forcibly assigning *pointers* and not the integer values themselves.

Comment: @jamesdlin, the application I'm working with does not allocate memory for those `my_struct` members, instead is assigns pointers to `netlink` buffer memory, obtained from `recv()`. This is just a design I have to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it safe to do the following?
>
> ```
> aa->a = (uint32_t *)&bb->b;
> ```

C allows you to convert between different object pointer types.  And having converted the value of the expression `&bb->b` to the type of `aa->a`, you may certainly assign the result to `aa->a`. In that sense, *that statement itself* is safe.

But it is **not** safe to afterward dereference `aa->a`.  The result of doing so is explicitly undefined.  Inasmuch as I infer that that's what you intend to do next, no, your overall plan is not safe.

If you want a pointer that can point to either a `uint32_t` or a `uint8_t`, then use `void *` or a `char *` or `unsigned char *`.  In the very likely event that `uint8_t` is an alias for `unsigned char`, you may also use a `uint8_t *`.

Comment: Disagree with the optimistic view of conversion safety here.  "C allows you to convert between different object pointer types" Hmmm: "If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined."  `bb->b` is not certainly aligned for `(uint32_t *)&bb->b` and this code risk UB - with or with out a later de-reference.  OTOH, perhaps `struct` all share the same alignment?

Comment: That's a good observation, @chux.  Two, actually.  Certainly all structure-pointer types have the same *representation*.  If we're nitpicking, then I don't think that actually requires them to have the same alignment requirement, but in practice, I don't think there's any reasonable likelihood of an alignment issue when converting a pointer to the first member of one structure to the type of the first member of another structure.